# Developing a Access Control List using NoSQL databases

Tags: sql, azure, nosql, authorization, acl

I'm about to develop a access control scheme for my new app, and because:

- this app will be deployed on azure
- I have managed not to use SQL so far
- table storage is cheaper
- table storage performance is good enough for me

I was wondering if there's a algorithm/scheme/"general implementation"/design that better leverages the power of table storage to handle ACL based authorization...

PS: I do know how to implement a ACL based authorization using traditional SQL...

Comment: I wonder why in 21st century and in the era of terms like Claims, Federation, Single-Sign-On, etc. you still want to go back in time in the (dark) ages of "Please create this username and password for my super service! I don't care that you might already have 20 other online identities I could use"? Not to mention that in Azure you have things like Azure Active Directory, Access Control Service. And last but not least - ThinkTecture's Identity Server. Just embrace the claims mantra. Your life will be easier. Your users will be happier!

Comment: You missunderstood me  my friend... i don't want to handle Authentication... just authorization...

Comment: @astaykov can you provide a real world example on how to store and relate claims in database rdbms or nosql?

Comment: It can be simple or it can be complicated.  In the simple world you're mapping a resource string to a username.  It gets a little more complicated mapping groups of groups to users and resources embedded within resources.  How much sophistication are you looking for?